# Starting new Project based on a GIT Project

Tags: git, github, versioning

I am starting a Project based on an existing (actively developing) CMS from GitHub. I will be using that Project as my base but adding my own changes and additions to its styling, models and architecture.

I am looking for some guidance in terms of how I should be tracking my changes but also be able to pull in changes and updates in the future.

Ex: This CMS system I am going to use has a stable version of v4.0.1 (tag) but they are actively adding features and bug fixes. Which they keep adding to the branch (4.x). So I have the branch 4.x checked out and I keep seeing the options to pull down the changes. I don't know if I should be pulling those changes regularly or I should check out Tag 4.0.1 and keep adding my changes locally and maybe set up a remote repository in my own GitHub account and keep pushing my changes there. And then lets say they release 4.0.2 or 4.1 then I can merge those changes and fix conflicts one by one?

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

You can fork the repository on GitHub to your own account. This will create your own, working copy without affecting the original repo. You can learn more about Forking [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/working-with-forks), as well instructions on how to keep Forks synchronized with the origin branch, [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork).

Comment: However I want my repository to be private. Its for Work.

Comment: @devbawa You can change repository privacy settings on forked repos, much like you can with any other repo.  See this article for the details: https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/github-how-to-make-a-fork-of-public-repository-private-6ee8cacaf9d3

Comment: I went with this article. It’s detailed and easy to follow. 

Only thing I am struggling with is that when I pushed to my private repo it pushed v4.x branch. As that’s the master branch of this repo. However the stable code marked with tag 4.0.1. Now my private repo is based on their 4.x branch which isn’t ‘stable’ but rather their working branch I think. 

Any idea if I can push from the headless ‘tag’ to my private repo ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new remote repository named *upstream* that points to the remote-repository:

```
git remote add upstream https://url-to-another-git-repo.git
```

Then you can merge all from the upstream to your local repository with following command:

```
git pull upstream
```

If you don't want to *merge* the changes automatically, then use `fetch` instead of `pull`:

```
git fetch upstream
```

If you want to pull a particular branch from another repository, use this command:

```
git pull https://url-to-another-git-repo.git branch-name --allow-unrelated-histories
```